# Nrwl/nx angular project throws ivy/ngcc error when importing modules from a custom package

Tags: angular, package, package.json, nrwl-nx

I'm working on moving the shared libs of my angular project to a separate package project, which will upload the packages to npm for the main project to download and reference. Before the migration, everything built and ran fine. Once I start referencing the npm packages, though, I get a build-time error when building any of my sub-apps:

```
'MyCustomModule' does not appear to be an NgModule class.

60     MyCustomModule,
       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  node_modules/@my-org/my-package/src/lib/my-custom.module.d.ts:1:22
    1 export declare class MyCustomModule {
                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    This likely means that the library (@my-org/my-package) which declares MyCustomModule has not been processed correctly by ngcc, or is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer version of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy.
```

My main project has the following package.json:

```json
{
  "name": "my-project",
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "postinstall": "patch-package --patch-dir ./tools/patches && ngcc --properties es2020 browser module main --first-only --create-ivy-entry-points",
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "15.2.4",
    "@angular/cdk": "15.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "15.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "15.2.4",
    "@angular/core": "15.2.4",
    "@angular/forms": "15.2.4",
    "@angular/material": "15.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "15.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "15.2.4",
    "@angular/router": "15.2.4",
    "@ctrl/ngx-codemirror": "^6.1.0",
    "@datadog/browser-rum": "^4.36.0",
    "@docusaurus/core": "2.4.0",
    "@docusaurus/preset-classic": "2.4.0",
    "@fullcalendar/angular": "^6.1.5",
    "@fullcalendar/core": "^6.1.5",
    "@fullcalendar/interaction": "^6.1.5",
    "@fullcalendar/resource-timeline": "^6.1.5",
    "@fullstory/browser": "^1.7.0",
    "@my-org/my-package": "1.0.0", <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    "@ngrx/component-store": "15.4.0",
    "@ngrx/effects": "15.4.0",
    "@ngrx/router-store": "15.4.0",
    "@ngrx/store": "15.4.0",
    "@ngx-formly/core": "^6.1.3",
    "@ngx-formly/material": "^6.1.3",
    "@ngx-pwa/local-storage": "^15.0.0",
    "@nrwl/angular": "15.9.0",
    "ag-grid-angular": "^29.2.0",
    "ag-grid-community": "^29.2.0",
    "angular-calendar": "^0.31.0",
    "angular-gridster2": "^15.0.4",
    "angularx-qrcode": "15.0.1",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "codemirror": "^5.65.9",
    "core-js": "^3.29.1",
    "docusaurus-lunr-search": "~2.3.2",
    "event-source-polyfill": "^1.0.31",
    "exceljs": "^4.3.0",
    "fast-xml-parser": "^3.21.1",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "highcharts": "~11.1.0",
    "highcharts-angular": "^3.1.2",
    "html2canvas": "^1.4.1",
    "jszip": "^3.10.1",
    "leaflet": "^1.9.3",
    "leaflet-bing-layer": "^3.3.1",
    "leaflet.markercluster": "^1.5.3",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.42",
    "ng2-fittext": "~1.3.0",
    "ngx-barcode6": "^1.0.22",
    "ngx-file-drop": "^15.0.0",
    "ngx-mask": "^15.1.0",
    "ngx-papaparse": "^7.0.0",
    "normalize.css": "^8.0.1",
    "normalizr": "^3.6.2",
    "react": "^17.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.0",
    "resize-observer": "^1.0.4",
    "rxjs": "^7.8.0",
    "systemjs": "^6.14.1",
    "systemjs-css-extra": "^1.0.2",
    "tslib": "^2.5.0",
    "util": "^0.11.1",
    "uuid": "^9.0.0",
    "xterm": "^5.1.0",
    "zone.js": "0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@actions/github": "^5.1.1",
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "0.1502.4",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "15.2.4",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "15.2.4",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "15.2.4",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "15.2.1",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "15.2.1",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "15.2.1",
    "@angular/cli": "15.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "15.2.4",
    "@angular/language-service": "15.2.4",
    "@commitlint/cli": "^13.2.1",
    "@commitlint/config-conventional": "^13.2.0",
    "@commitlint/prompt-cli": "^13.2.1",
    "@compodoc/compodoc": "^1.1.19",
    "@datadog/datadog-ci": "2.14.0",
    "@ngrx/schematics": "15.4.0",
    "@ngrx/store-devtools": "15.4.0",
    "@nrwl/cli": "15.8.9",
    "@nrwl/cypress": "11.6.3",
    "@nrwl/devkit": "15.8.9",
    "@nrwl/eslint-plugin-nx": "15.8.9",
    "@nrwl/jest": "15.8.9",
    "@nrwl/linter": "15.8.9",
    "@nrwl/storybook": "16.5.3",
    "@nrwl/workspace": "15.8.9",
    "@nx-plus/docusaurus": "^15.0.0-rc.0",
    "@schematics/angular": "~15.1.0",
    "@types/file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "@types/fs-extra": "^11.0.1",
    "@types/jest": "29.5.0",
    "@types/leaflet": "^1.9.3",
    "@types/leaflet.markercluster": "^1.5.1",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.191",
    "@types/node": "18.15.10",
    "@types/uuid": "^9.0.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "5.56.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "5.56.0",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "^0.15.0",
    "babel-loader": "9.1.2",
    "cypress": "^5.6.0",
    "dotenv": "16.0.3",
    "eslint": "8.36.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "8.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-cypress": "^2.12.1",
    "fs-extra": "^11.1.1",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "^2.0.6",
    "husky": "^8.0.3",
    "ignore": "^5.2.4",
    "jasmine-marbles": "0.9.2",
    "jest": "29.5.0",
    "jest-canvas-mock": "2.5.0",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "29.5.0",
    "jest-preset-angular": "13.0.1",
    "lint-staged": "^12.5.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.6.1",
    "mock-socket": "^9.2.1",
    "ng-mocks": "^14.7.3",
    "nx": "15.8.9",
    "patch-package": "^6.5.1",
    "postcss": "^8.4.21",
    "postcss-color-mod-function": "^3.0.3",
    "postcss-custom-properties": "^13.1.4",
    "prettier": "2.8.7",
    "puppeteer": "^10.4.0",
    "rimraf": "^4.4.1",
    "ts-jest": "29.0.5",
    "ts-node": "10.9.1",
    "typescript": "~4.8.2",
    "webpack": "5.76.1",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^4.8.0",
    "webpack-manifest-plugin": "^5.0.0"
  }
}
```

I've tried changing the postinstall ngcc command to the following without change:

- `ngcc`
- `ngcc --properties es2020 browser module main --first-only`
- `ngcc --properties es2020 browser module main`
- `ngcc --properties es2015 browser module main`

There is another custom package made by someone else that works as expected. When comparing what the packages look like in my project's node_modules, I see very different outputs. Does this mean that there's a problem with how I'm building the package for npm?

[image: new v old package]

The old package uses the builder `@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser` and appears to force a few things to get it to work (its setup as a single application project, not a package project), whereas mine uses `@nrwl/js:tsc`